# Multithread Directory and File Search

Tags: multithreading, recursion, directory, mutex

I am new to semaphores and the concepts of mutual exclusion. I am supposed to recursively text search in files through directories using multithreading. The number of threads is to be given by the user.

The issue with this code is it goes through one directory and then waits. I cannot figure out what is wrong.I am getting a segmentation fault error. Cannot figure out why is this happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
using namespace std;


#include <stdio.h>

int iDirectories=0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
sem_t semaphore1;
char searchStringThread[PATH_MAX];

int directories=0;


class directoryQueue
{
private:
struct Node
{
    char directoryPath[PATH_MAX];
    Node *next;
};
Node *front;
Node *rear;
Node *nodeCount;

public:

    directoryQueue(void)
    {
        front=NULL;
        rear=NULL;
        nodeCount=0;
    }


    void Enqueue(char array[PATH_MAX])

    {
        Node *newNode;
        newNode=new Node;

        strcpy(newNode->directoryPath,array);
        newNode->next=NULL;
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            front=newNode;
            rear=newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            rear->next=newNode;
            rear=newNode;
        }
        nodeCount++;
    }
    char * Dequeue(void)
    {
        Node *temp;

        if (isEmpty())
            cout << "Error ! Empty Queue "<<endl;
        else
        {
            char *deque;
            deque=new char[PATH_MAX];
            strcpy(deque,front->directoryPath);

            temp = front->next;
            front = temp;
            nodeCount--;
            return deque;
        }

    }

    bool isEmpty(void)
    {
        if(nodeCount)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    void makeNull(void)
    {
        while(!isEmpty())
        {
            Dequeue();
        }
    }

    ~directoryQueue(void)
    {
        makeNull();
    }
};
directoryQueue saveDirectory;



void *threadHandler(void *)
{
int thpath_length;
char thPath[PATH_MAX];
char saveITDirectory[PATH_MAX];
char itDirectory[PATH_MAX];
int threadCount;
struct dirent *iWalker;
DIR *iDirectory;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
threadCount=iDirectories++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
sem_wait(&semaphore1);
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
strcpy(itDirectory,saveDirectory.Dequeue());
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

iDirectory=opendir(itDirectory);
if(iDirectory==NULL)
{
    cout<<"Error"<<endl;
    cout<<itDirectory<<"  Cannot be Opened"<<endl;
    exit(10000);
}
while((iWalker=readdir(iDirectory)) !=NULL)
{
    if(iWalker->d_type==DT_REG)
    {




        strcpy(saveITDirectory,iWalker->d_name);
        cout<<itDirectory<<"/"<<endl;
        if (strcmp (saveITDirectory, "..") == 0 ||
            strcmp (saveITDirectory, ".") == 0) 
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {


            thpath_length = snprintf(thPath,PATH_MAX,"%s/%s",itDirectory,saveITDirectory);

            cout<<thPath<<endl;
            if (thpath_length >= PATH_MAX) 
            {
                cout<<"Path is too long"<<endl;
                exit (1000);
            }
            ifstream openFile;
            openFile.open(thPath);
            char line[1500];
            int currentLine = 0;
            if (openFile.is_open()) {
                while (openFile.good()) {
                    currentLine++;
                    openFile.getline(line, 1500);
                    if (strstr(line, searchStringThread) != NULL){
                        cout<<thPath<<": "<<currentLine<<": "<<line<<endl;
                        cout<<"This was performed by Thread no. "<<threadCount<<endl;
                        cout<<"ID :"<<pthread_self();
                    }
                }
            }
            openFile.close();    
        }
    }
    if (closedir (iDirectory)) 
    {
        cout<<"Unable to close  "<<itDirectory<<endl;
        exit (1000);
    }
}

}



void walkThroughDirectory(char directory_name[PATH_MAX],char  searchString[PATH_MAX])
{

DIR * directory;
struct dirent * walker;
char d_name[PATH_MAX];
int path_length;
char path[PATH_MAX];
directory=opendir(directory_name);
if(directory==NULL)
{
    cout<<"Error"<<endl;
    cout<<directory_name<<"  Cannot be Opened"<<endl;
    exit(10000);
}
while((walker=readdir(directory)) !=NULL)
{




    strcpy(d_name,walker->d_name);
    cout<<directory_name<<"/"<<endl;
    if (strcmp (d_name, "..") == 0 ||
        strcmp (d_name, ".") == 0) 
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {


        path_length = snprintf(path,PATH_MAX,"%s/%s",directory_name,d_name);

        cout<<path<<endl;
        if (path_length >= PATH_MAX) 
        {
            cout<<"Path is too long"<<endl;
            exit (1000);
        }
        if(walker->d_type==DT_DIR)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            saveDirectory.Enqueue(path);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            sem_post(&semaphore1);
            directories++;
            walkThroughDirectory (path,searchString);
        }
        else if(walker->d_type==DT_REG)
        {   
            ifstream openFile;
            openFile.open(path);
            char line[1500];
            int currentLine = 0;
            if (openFile.is_open()) {
                while (openFile.good()) {
                    currentLine++;
                    openFile.getline(line, 1500);
                    if (strstr(line, searchString) != NULL)
                        cout<<path<<": "<<currentLine<<": "<<line<<endl;
                }
            }
            openFile.close();    
        }


    }

}

if (closedir (directory)) 
{
    cout<<"Unable to close  "<<directory_name<<endl;
    exit (1000);
}
}













int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
char * name;

cout<<"Total Directories  "<< directories<<endl;



name=get_current_dir_name();
cout<<"Current Directory is:  "<<name<<endl;
sem_init(&semaphore1,0,0);
strcpy(searchStringThread,argv[1]);
int number_of_threads=atoi(argv[3]);
pthread_t threads[number_of_threads];




walkThroughDirectory(argv[2],argv[1]);
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
saveDirectory.Enqueue(argv[2]);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
sem_post(&semaphore1);

for(int i=0;i<number_of_threads;i++)
{
    pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,threadHandler,NULL);
}
for(int j=0;j<number_of_threads;j++)
{
    pthread_join(threads[j],NULL);
}
while(saveDirectory.isEmpty())
{
    cout<<"Queue is Empty"<<endl;
    cout<<"Exiting"<<endl;
    exit(10000);
}
free(name);
cout<<"Total Directories  "<< directories<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple bug where you lock a mutex twice instead of unlocking it when you're done:

```
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        saveDirectory.Enqueue(path);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
```

should be:

```
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        saveDirectory.Enqueue(path);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Note: this isn't to say that there aren't other problems - just that this is probably your immediate problem.

The biggest problem is that it looks like you put directories on the `saveDirectory` queue (so another thread can pull it off to work on it), then go ahead an process that directory recursively in the thread that just put it on the queue. I think you'll need to give some more thought on how the work will be divided among the threads.

A couple of more minor comments:

- you might want to consider using `std::string` if that's permitted. It should make some of your string handling simpler (you leak memory from the data returned from  `directoryQueue::Dequeue()`, for example)
- if the primary reason for the existence of the  `directoryQueue` class is to hold work items for multiple threads, then maybe it should manage it's own mutex so callers don't need to deal with that complexity

Comment: Can you Please explain the saveDirectory Queue problem?@michael burr

Comment: @mobykin: I'm sorry - I only had a few minutes to look over the code.  I believe I misunderstood the purpose of `walkThroughDirectory()`.